[Slam Toolbox]Map is overlapping and doesn't make loop_closure
Required Info:
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Installation type: binaries
ROS Version : ROS2 Humble
Version or commit hash: release version
Laser unit: RP Lidar


We mapped it on the map above and using the async mode with default parameters. It did not connect the pose graph nodes between the point where we started mapping and the point where we finished mapping. It made a small modification to the map but did not complete the loop closure. It did not connect the pose graph nodes between the point where we started mapping and the point where we finished mapping. It made a small modification to the map but did not complete the loop closure. For examples.



Can you help me what to do in this case, which parameters I can tune or any other solution.
Additional information

We are use the EKF with fusing wheel encoder and 6 DOF IMU. I have looked at other issues related to this incident. It is generally said to be related to the quality of the odometry. I think the odometry we use in my tests is of good quality.
Map size 142 m (height) x 389 m (Width).
If you would like a bag file to help me, you can contact me by e-mail.
Thank you in advance for your help.

